# $\mathbb{Z}_{11} [x]/\langle x^2-2\rangle $ and $\mathbb{Z}_{11} [x]/\langle x^2-3\rangle$ are not isomorphic

Tags: ring-theory

I'm sory, I posted another problem.
Show that $\mathbb{Z}_{11} [x]/\langle x^2-2\rangle $ and $\mathbb{Z}_{11} [x]/\langle x^2-3\rangle$ are not isomorphic

Comment: You don't have to be sorry, but please don't use the imperative "show" either. How far do you get yourself on this problem? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Again, please read the FAQ and follow the rules of the site.  http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1803/how-to-ask-a-homework-question

Answer (score 4):

The following steps lead to a solution:

1. $x^2 - 2$ has no solutions over the field of $11$ elements, while $x^2 - 3$ has a solution (namely $x = 5$).
2. The former ring is therefore a field, while the latter ring is not a field.
3. Conclude.